# What is the purpose of both Main and Renderer folders in Electron Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron, electron-builder

I have recently started working on Electron and I came across electron-builder; this tool uses electron-webpack as the standard boilerplate, so I tried to understand how the last one worked; unfortunately I wasn't successful in finding the right documentation (I mean, I've found the offical documentantion, but nothing about what I was looking for).

When you create a simple app with electron-webpack there is a src folder; inside this folder there are a Main folder and a Renderer folder. I know how electron creates different process for each renderer, but I don't understand how should I use the renderer folder... I mean, all of the code in my applciation executed by the render process is inside the  tag in my ejs files.
I already know that I can disable the uses of the renderer folder but I wanted to know how it can be efficiently used, just to learn new things.

If you can link me any guide or tutorial I will be very grateful.
Apologize for any grammar error, I'm not mother tongue.

Thank you for your time!